# Retrieving original images after blending two images together

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Alright, say I have two images, img1 and img2. Now I create a new image, img3, by blending img1 and img2 one on top of the other. Is it possible to retrieve either img1 or img2 from img3?

I was able to create img3 by blending two uiimages together but I'm at a lost when it comes to separating the original two images from the newly created image. I've tried searching for information on how to achieve this but have hit a wall as I am not quite sure what's the proper term for this process.

I'll appreciate any guidance here as I am completely stumped.

Comment: So exactly what is the issue? Obviously you do not have access to "img1" or "img2", because you wouldn't be asking things. But, what then *are* you asking? Do you have more details? Maybe some code? It's hard to help you when you ask such a vague question.

Answer (score 1):

If you are drawing two image using `drawInRect` and then get image by `UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext` then the answer is no.

> drawInRect:
>
> This method draws the entire image in the current graphics
> context, respecting the image’s orientation setting.

This method is drawing the image on top of another by pixel, not creating two layer so that you can get a specific layer later.

Comment: ah I see. Is there a way to create and save an image so that both layers remain intact so I can separate the layers afterwards?

Comment: @RickyTheCoder Well sadly no. If you want to output an image to `UIImage`, you will not be able to separate layers later. But if you just want the effect of two image overlapping, you can create `CALayer` on top of an `UIImage`

Comment: Thanks for your help. It's seems I'm going to have figure out another method then.